# Parse XML data with additional node information

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StockLevels>
    <CreatedAt>2017-04-29</CreatedAt>

    <Products>
       <Product>
       <Id>124</Id>
       <Stock date="2017-04-27" qty="8502">1020</StockLevel>
       <Stock date="2017-04-28" qty="10502">1235</StockLevel>
       </Product>

       <Product>
       <Id>125</Id>
       <Stock date="2017-04-27" qty="19">49</StockLevel>
       <Stock date="2017-04-28" qty="2019">2049</StockLevel>
       </Product>
    </Products>

</StockLevels>
```

I have tried to fetch the XML file and convert it into SimpleXMLElement, however, I could only get the main XML node value and not the `date` and `qty` attributes.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show any code you've got, even if it's not working.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php